# What's wrong with my code for a circularly linked list?

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, linked-list

I'm learning C and data structure. I'm trying to create a circular linked list with one sentinel and print 6 numbers. But I'm having a hard time with this assignment.  I've been working on this for a few hours.  I am stuck.  I hope someone can help me take a look at my code and give me some hints on what the issue is.  Thanks in advance for your time!

I tried to add 3 numbers in the front and 3 numbers in the back and print out the number in the front and back, it works.  But when I tried to print the whole list, I could only get 3 numbers or run into an error.

```
    struct DLink {
    TYPE value;         /* value of the link */
    struct DLink * next;    /* pointer to the next link */
    struct DLink * prev;    /* pointer to the previous link */
};

# define TYPE_SENTINEL_VALUE DBL_MAX 


struct cirListDeque {
    int size;                  /* number of links in the deque */
    struct DLink *Sentinel;         /* pointer to the sentinel */
};

/* internal functions prototypes */
struct DLink* _createLink (TYPE val);
void _addLinkAfter(struct cirListDeque *q, struct DLink *lnk, struct DLink *newLnk);

/* Initialize deque.

    param:  q       pointer to the deque
    pre:    q is not null
    post:   q->backSentinel is allocated and q->size equals zero
*/
void _initCirListDeque (struct cirListDeque *q) 
{
    assert(q != 0);

    //allocate the sentinel
    q->Sentinel = malloc(sizeof(struct DLink));
    assert(q->Sentinel != 0);

    //the start point and end point are equal to each other
    //q->Sentinel->next = q->Sentinel;
    q->Sentinel->next = q->Sentinel->prev;

    //set the size of the deque
    q->size = 0;
} 

/*
 create a new circular list deque

 */

struct cirListDeque *createCirListDeque()
{
    struct cirListDeque *newCL = malloc(sizeof(struct cirListDeque));
    _initCirListDeque(newCL);
    return(newCL);
}


//Create a link for a value.
struct DLink * _createLink (TYPE val)
{
    /* FIXME: you must write this */
    /*temporary return value..you may need to change it*/
    //Create a new link to store the value
    struct DLink *new_lnk = malloc(sizeof(struct DLink));
    assert(new_lnk != 0);
    new_lnk->value = val;

    return new_lnk;
}

//Adds a link after another link
void _addLinkAfter(struct cirListDeque *q, struct DLink *lnk, struct DLink *newLnk)
{
    assert(q != 0);
    assert(lnk != 0);
    assert(newLnk != 0);

    //The existing link is before the new link
    lnk->next = newLnk;
    newLnk->prev = lnk;

    //The link that was originally after the existing link is after the new link
    newLnk->next = q->Sentinel->next;

    //The new link is the last link
    //q->Sentinel->prev = newLnk;

    //update the size field
    q->size++;
}

// Adds a link to the back of the deque
void addBackCirListDeque (struct cirListDeque *q, TYPE val)
{
    /* FIXME: you must write this */
    assert(q != 0);

    //Create the new back link
    struct DLink *new_backLnk = _createLink(val);
    struct DLink *tmp = q->Sentinel->prev;

    q->Sentinel->prev = new_backLnk;
    new_backLnk->prev = tmp;
    new_backLnk->next = q->Sentinel->next;

}

// Adds a link to the front of the deque
void addFrontCirListDeque(struct cirListDeque *q, TYPE val)
{
    /* FIXME: you must write this */
    assert(q != 0);

    //create a temp link for the link that is originally after the sentinel
    struct DLink *tmp = q->Sentinel->next;

    //allocate the new front link
    struct DLink *new_frontLnk = _createLink(val);

    //add the new front link after the Sentinel
    _addLinkAfter(q, q->Sentinel, new_frontLnk);

    //Put the old front link after the new front link
    new_frontLnk->next = tmp;

    //new_frontLnk->prev = q->Sentinel->prev;

}

// Get the value of the front of the deque
TYPE frontCirListDeque(struct cirListDeque *q) 
{
    /* FIXME: you must write this */     
    /*temporary return value..you may need to change it*/
    assert(q != 0);
    assert(q->size > 0);

    return q->Sentinel->next->value;
}

// Get the value of the back of the deque
TYPE backCirListDeque(struct cirListDeque *q)
{
    /* FIXME: you must write this */     
    /*temporary return value..you may need to change it*/
    assert(q != 0);
    assert(q->size > 0);

    return q->Sentinel->prev->value;

}


// Check whether the deque is empty
int isEmptyCirListDeque(struct cirListDeque *q) {
    /* FIXME: you must write this */
    /*temporary return value..you may need to change it*/
    assert(q != 0);

    if (q->size == 0)
        return 1;

    return 0;
}

// Print the links in the deque from front to back
void printCirListDeque(struct cirListDeque *q)
{
    assert(q != 0);
    assert(!isEmptyCirListDeque(q));

    for (int i = 0; i < q->size; i++)
    {
        printf("The value is %g\n", q->Sentinel->next->value);
        q->Sentinel->next = q->Sentinel->next->next;
    }

}
```

Comment: side note: you should not `assert()` `malloc`'s return value. you should handle failure gracefully, as it is an error that might occur at runction even in a perfect code.

Comment: Names beginning with an underscore `_` are reserved for the compiler. It doesn't appear to buy you anything, either.

Comment: Do you have size ++ after addBackCirListDeque or addFrontCirListDeque?

Comment: In `printCirListDeque` you probably don't want to change the value of the Sentinel itself, but rather a temporary pointer.

Answer (score 2):

In this code the `malloc` does not initialize `q->Sentinel` and you do not initialize `q->Sentinel->prev` so the value of `q->Sentinel->next` and `q->Sentinel->prev` is undefined. So, you should have the `q->Sentinel->prev = q->Sentinel;` line uncommented.

```
void _initCirListDeque (struct cirListDeque *q) 
{
    assert(q != 0);

    //allocate the sentinel
    q->Sentinel = malloc(sizeof(struct DLink));

    if( !q->Sentinel )
    {
         printf( "out of memory\n" );
         exit( -1 );
    }

    //the start point and end point are equal to each other
    q->Sentinel->prev = q->Sentinel->next = q->Sentinel;

    //set the size of the deque
    q->size = 0;
}
```

In the `_addLinkAfter` you need to preserve the current `next` attribute of `lnk` before you do anything, then you need to insert your link into the existing one...

```
void _addLinkAfter(struct cirListDeque *q, struct DLink *lnk, struct DLink *newLnk)
{
    // preserve current linkage

    newLnk->prev = lnk;
    newLnk->next = lnk->next;

    // link in new record

    lnk->next = newLnk;
    newLnk->next->prev = newLnk;

    q->size++;
}
```

you can optimize your `addBackCirListDeque` to use the existing `_addLinkAfter`

```
void addBackCirListDeque(struct cirListDeque *q, TYPE val)
{
    _addLinkAfter( q, q->Sentinel->prev, _createLink(val) );
}
```

and the same for `addFrontCirListDeque`

```
void addFrontCirListDeque(struct cirListDeque *q, TYPE val)
{
    _addLinkAfter( q, q->Sentinel, _createLink(val) );
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  I have 3 print statements.  The first one is to use the print method, which I posted earlier.  I got all the numbers in order.  However, when I want to print the number in the front, I didn't get the first number.  I got a number in the middle.  I don't understand why.  I'll post my updated code.  Really appreciate your help!

Comment: Hi. I found out the issue is in my print method. Problem is solved. Thank you!

Comment: Can you please show your print method?  I am having a similar issue.  It prints fine until after I do the reverse, then it prints all values, but hangs and the program will not end/exit the print function.